# Can't get GET_ACCOUNTS permission for Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My AndroidManifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>`

My build.gradle:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

My Activity's `onCreate()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AnyMailMainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            } else {
                mContactPermissionGranted = true;
            }
        } else {
            mContactPermissionGranted = true;
        }
```

My `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mContactPermissionGranted = true;
                } else {
                    mContactPermissionGranted = false;
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

```

Still, I am neither getting a 'request contact dialog' not getting any permission granted for GET_ACCOUNTS.
The purpose is to get the google emails from the device for Android M and above without showing google's account picker. Just the way we used to get the list of accounts before Android M.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested whether you can already access the account or are you making an assumption based on no dialog?

The `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission is under the contacts group, so if you already granted another permission in that group (`READ_CONTACTS` or `WRITE_CONTACTS`) you already have accounts access.

One other thing to be aware of while testing - the documentation now states:

> if an app shares the signature of the authenticator that manages an account, it does not need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about that account.

Comment: If I already have access, then I should get permission_granted in the checkSelfPermission step which I don't.

Comment: You haven't included manifest - does your activity have noHistory? What platform are you running against, presumably M?